Color is see through
I have the following code
ZStack(alignment: .top) {
    Color(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, opacity: 1)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 32)
    
    ScrollView {
        VStack {
            Text("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.")
        }
    }
}

Here's the result

I expected the red color to fully cover the text but it's see through, I need to cover the text with the color
I was actually trying to add gradient on top of scrollview but I got the following result

Then I change to plain color and it's still see through

If you just remove the .frame modifier from the color then it will fill all of the background. To restrict it to the VStack only, try applying as .background to the VStack instead.

@BenzyNeez I do not want to fill all of the background, I want it to be 50 points and I do not want it to be see through, when user scrolls the text, user should not see the text, it should be covered with the color

Following from your comment, I think you just need two small changes:

add top padding to the ScrollView to equal the height of the red area
move the red color below the ScrollView, so that the red layer is higher than the scrolled layer in the ZStack.

You might want to add .ignoresSafeArea to the red color too, so that it extends up to the top of the screen.
ZStack(alignment: .top) {
    ScrollView {
        VStack {
            Text("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.")
        }
    }
    .padding(.top, 50)

    Color.red
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .frame(height: 50)
}



Thanks for accepting the answer! Actually, I think it's better if the padding is added to the ScrollView instead of to the VStack, answer updated. This way, the scroll indicators do not disappear behind the red area.

Why you don't just remove the whole ZStack and make something like this:
VStack(spacing: .zero) {
   Color.red
       .ignoresSafeArea()
       .frame(height: 50)

    ScrollView {
        Text("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.")
    }

}


Color should be on top of text covering it
